# Active Learning in AllenNLP v2.0.1

Tags: allennlp

I tried implementing an Active Learning procedure in AllenNLP v2.0.1 . However, with the current `GradientDescentTrainer` implementation, I am unable to continue training on a new batch of `Instance`.

The model (also trained using AllenNLP) has finished training for the predefined number of epochs on an initial training dataset. I restore the model using the `Model.from_archive` method and a `Trainer` is instantiated for it using the `Trainer.from_params` static constructor.

Thereafter, when I attempt to continue training on a new batch of `Instance` by calling `trainer.train()`, it skips training because of the following code snippet in the `_try_train` method,

```py
for epoch in range(epoch_counter, self._num_epochs)
```

This is because the `epoch_counter` is restored to 5, which is from training on the initial training data previously. This is the relevant code snippet for it,

```py
def _try_train(self) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], int]:
    try:
        epoch_counter = self._restore_checkpoint()
```

`self._num_epochs` is also 5 which I assume is the number of epochs defined in my .jsonnet training configuration file.

Simply, my requirement is to load an AllenNLP model that has already been trained and to continue training it on a new batch of Instances (single Instance actually which I would load using a `SimpleDataLoader`)

I have also attached the configuration for the Trainer below. The model I am using is a custom wrapper around the BasicClassifier, solely for the purpose of logging additional metrics.

Thanks in advance.

```json
"trainer": {
  "num_epochs": 5,
  "patience": 1, // for early stopping
  "grad_norm": 5.0,
  "validation_metric": "+accuracy",
  "optimizer": {
    "type": "adam",
    "lr": 0.001
  },
  "callbacks": [
    {
      "type": "tensorboard"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple of advice:

1. don't turn the recover flag on when you run the command line or through script
2. specify a different serialization directory for your second training